# typescript: call signatures example question

Tags: typescript

I am learning about typescript call signatures and need the help of a typescript expert:

The following code compiles, but running it in 'typescript playground' results in a runtime error.
The runtime error is: ([ERR]: logFunc is not a function)

```
    type LogFunctionWithPrefixCB = {
        logPrefix: string;
        (stringToLog: string) : void; // that's the shortcut - supposedly type  LogFunctionWithPrefixCB is callable (can call it as a function)
    }

    function makeLogFunctionWithPrefixCB( prefixStr : string) : LogFunctionWithPrefixCB {

        let loggerFunc = function(this : LogFunctionWithPrefixCB, stringToLog: string) {
            console.log(`${this.logPrefix}: ${stringToLog}`);
        };

        let ret = {
            logPrefix: prefixStr,
            call : loggerFunc
        };

        return ret as LogFunctionWithPrefixCB;

    }

    // using the
    function doSomething(logFunc : LogFunctionWithPrefixCB) {
        logFunc("hello world");    // no compilation error - but get runtime error "logFunc is not a function "
    }

    let logger = makeLogFunctionWithPrefixCB("prefix:");
    doSomething(logger);
```

Now the next example does not compile, but it runs and gives the expected result: (see logfunc.call(...))
The typescript compilation error is: "Expected 2 arguments, but got 1."

Tried lots of typescript versions - all with the same result.

```
    type LogFunctionWithPrefixCB = { 
        logPrefix: string;
        (stringToLog: string) : void; // that's the shortcut - supposedly type  LogFunctionWithPrefixCB is callable (can call it as a function)
    }

    function makeLogFunctionWithPrefixCB( prefixStr : string) : LogFunctionWithPrefixCB {

        let loggerFunc = function(this : LogFunctionWithPrefixCB, stringToLog: string) {
            console.log(`${this.logPrefix}: ${stringToLog}`);
        };

        let ret = {
            logPrefix: prefixStr,
            call : loggerFunc
        };

        return ret as LogFunctionWithPrefixCB;
     
    }

    // using the 
    function doSomething(logFunc : LogFunctionWithPrefixCB) {
        logFunc.call("hello world");    // works, but typescript compilation error "Expected 2 arguments, but got 1 "
    }

    let logger = makeLogFunctionWithPrefixCB("prefix:");
    doSomething(logger);
```

Comment: It fails because you're using the `as` operator - which tells TS to ignore its type reasoning engine and to assume you know better than the compiler - but in this case, TypeScript is right: your `ret` object is not a `LogFunctionWithPrefixCB`.

Comment: FWIW, your ` type LogFunctionWithPrefixCB` describes an object-type, not a function-type, so it isn't really a "LogFunction"...

Comment: the .call syntax works, despite the same cast. That's the only way that i got it to work, somehow. Would appreciate any insight.

Comment: But you didn't "get it to work": when you use the `as` operator you're basically telling TSC to _lie_.

Comment: No - i am creating a javascript dictionary with the desired structure. Would appreciate any advise on how to make it better.

Comment: I don't know what to say about the book you're learning from, but it's *very* unusual for the `this` context of a function to be the function itself, and that part is not trivial to get working.  You could do it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/w6z9Ew) instead; does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example! (I pasted your answer into the question) I saw this construct mentioned in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html - but they didn't explain how to make one.

Comment: removed your answer from the question. thanks again!

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to make a function that also has properties on it.  The easiest way to do so is to create your function value as a `const` and then just add the properties afterward, which is [explicitly supported in TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions).  Something like:

```
const f = function(){ /*⋯*/ };
f.prop = 123;
```

That is the basic approach you can take.  But:

---

Your function is of the form

```
const f = function(stringToLog) {
  console.log(`${this.logPrefix}: ${stringToLog}`);
}
f.logPrefix = prefixStr;
```

but the only way that would work is if the [`this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) on which the function is called happens to be the function itself.  And this is very, very unlikely.  If you just call it like `f("")`, then there's no `this` context at all (it would almost certainly be `undefined`).  You'd have to [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) it to itself before calling it, like `f.bind(f)("")`.  And if you wanted this to happen *automatically*, then you'd need to define something like `const g = f.bind(f)`.  But *now* `g` is just a function without the extra `logPrefix` property.  It's a mess, and much more complicated than necessary.  Messing with `this` is probably not what you want.

Instead you can just refer to the function object directly where you were using `this`.  That brings us to this implementation:

```
function makeLogFunctionWithPrefixCB(prefixStr: string): LogFunctionWithPrefixCB {
  const loggerFunc = function (stringToLog: string) {
    console.log(`${loggerFunc.logPrefix}: ${stringToLog}`);
  };
  loggerFunc.logPrefix = prefixStr;
  return loggerFunc;
}
```

That compiles without error, and we can see how it works:

```
function doSomething(logFunc: LogFunctionWithPrefixCB) {
  logFunc("hello world");
}

let logger = makeLogFunctionWithPrefixCB("prefix");
doSomething(logger); // "prefix: hello world" 
logger.logPrefix = "changedPrefix";
doSomething(logger); // "changedPrefix: hello world"
```

Looks good.  The `logger` object is of type `LogFunctionWithPrefixCB` and so it has a `logPrefix` property, and if we alter that property it alters the behavior of `logger`'s function in the expected way.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9gcwGIFcB2BjYBLOaDq2wAFgAoBOEAZtgB4DCAQlALxQDeAUFFADaIVqdAFxQAzsHLY0CANzcoACglSZAFTjwEoldIQBKUQDc42ACbyAvp05V0WXGigBbAIYBrCFtSYceQiSCNAyMimCUwQDKkjqSeoawiD4O-kRkEXRMHAoYeBJ8iAgQ5MmsUHa+jkq66pqIsaoG2Tw8uWhicLwQAHT8CIoABgAk7H1FJfa9Ahm0lqIjNQgaWpYD+vI8lhsFCOPJUwhBdGXhQrTR5NuUwCjkTmPFyVY2FSlOZnCRcM4QJHqKfWSom89j8BDSRxC+maO2SigARMQILx+FAAO5wci8Mzw9acaycLrAHbjMpuTwgyqpQIzJgI07BXHyD5fH5-GQAwrFdZQAD0vKg8IZIigSJRcHRmOx8KghK55AOkLK8IwxFcMggZkh8OZn2+v2I-we5B5-MFqvVRS1M1EYtRGKxOKgQA)